# using header() is good in this context

Tags: php

I have a user who registered on my website with some email and password. As soon as he registers we will send a confirmation code to his email and ask him to enter the number to sign up.

Unfortunately there is a possibility that the user may fill the data and may logoff today without entering the confirmation code and he may come back tomorow and login with his registered email. So I would check his email in the database and if he is registered and if his email is under the approval of code sent to his email then I want to redirect him to a page indicating that "a code has been sent to your email respond to your code to sign up" else if he is already registered and there is no pending approvals then redirect him to his profile.

I am not sure the way to do it. I was thinking to use this: if user is under approval then `header('location confirmation.php')` and if he is approved then `header('location profile.php')` but I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it. Can headers be used for this purpose? or what is the alternate solution to do it. Please help me with this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Please remember to add an `exit;` call after all calls to `header()` when changing locations, otherwise the entire page is processed and sent to the client.  This can be a big security problem, depending on the page content.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Like this: `header('Location: some_page.php'); exit;`

Comment: but why may i know ?sorry im kinda new bee to this functions in php thats why could you please update your answer explaning why i need to use exit function ?

Comment: I *did* explain why in my answer already.  If you don't exit after the redirect, the entire page is processed and sent to the client's browser.  If this was a secure page (admin page or something), and it had information on it that the user shouldn't see, they would still be able to capture it and see it.

Answer (score 0):

Headers can be used for any purpose that involves changing the response headers. By all means, you can have an `if` statement that sets one `Location` header if true, and a different one otherwise. Just remember that the correct format is `header("Location: confirmation.php");` - ie, an uppercase `L` and a `:`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is were the location header should been used.

---

It is `Location: confirmation.php`, you forgot the `:`.